# React Ionic hooks Component setValue isnt working

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks

I've made a component that has a select option from Ionic/React where I have an object called `licenseValue`. However, when I try to `setLicenseValue`, if I try to `console` the `licenseValue` "value", it doesn't update the value.

```
import licenseValuesArray from './somewhere'

const [licenseValues, setLicenseValues] = useState(licenseValuesArray);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLicenseValues(licenseValuesArray);
  }, [licenseValuesArray]);
const [licenseValue, setLicenseValue] = useState(0);

<IonSelect
            value="value"
            okText="Okay"
            cancelText="Dismiss"
            onIonChange={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              let a = e.detail.value;
              setLicenseValue(a);
              console.log(a, "defina periodo");//retrieve the "a" value
              console.log(licenseValue, "defina periodo");//doesnt retrieve the value from setLicenseValue
            }}
          >
            {licenseValues.map((item) => (
              <IonSelectOption key={item.title} value={item}>
                {item.title}
              </IonSelectOption>
            ))}
          </IonSelect>
```

I'm using React / Ionic / hooks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to keep in mind that in React [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). In particular, the `useState` hook is not going to give you an updated value for `licenseValue` until the next render cycle. So the sample code you posted will aways log the previous value.

A better way log if it has changed or not would be to move your `console.log` to a `useEffect` hook that executes each time `licenseValue` changes, giving you the current value.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(licenseValue);
}, [licenseValue]);
```